# Using PHP - How to get $value based on a file name (e.g. value-value.php)?

Tags: php, import, get, metadata

Is it possible to get/import/generate $values based on file names? For example, if the file name were red-green.php, I want the values imported to the page as `<?value1='$red' value2='$green';?>`. Then, I can do whatever is needed for meta descriptions or content with these values. The reason for this I want to use a template approach for both meta data and content. (e.g. meta description="What is your favorite color? echo $value1 or echo $value2 ?") If I could import these values based on a file's name, it would make it much easier to dynamically create pages without tinkering with each one. I could just create file names like red-green.php, black-yellow.php, etc. Any thoughts on how to do this? Or, is there a better way? Also, please feel free to suggest more efficient alternative methods to accomplish this. I could see a good solution for this would be for values within a page to be generated based on a CSV txt or other database, but I haven't delved into that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way. These should all be in one file. Your file content should be generated based on GET arguments (or clean url request if using an MVC type setup). The url would be something like this:

```
color.php?color1=red&color2=green
```

You could then get these argument values in your code like so:

```
echo $_GET['color1'];
echo $_GET['color2'];
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working awesome. I used 'x' & 'y' instead of 'color1' & 'color2'. It works beautifully. In the URL, I can use color.php?x=red&y=green or color.php?x=I+like+red+and+green. The desired output is very customizable and saves a lot of time. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` which includes the file name and then parse it and create your variables.

its really a bad practice but you can set a dynamic variable like this:

```
$varName = 'var1';
$$varName = 'Value';
echo $var1 // will give you Value;
```

Comment: Thank you. Could summarize without getting too technical, what makes it a bad practice? Does it have to do with efficient performance, or other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess would be a good idea in this case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.php$ /file.php?value1=$1&value2=$2 [L]
```

So when you go to:

> red-green.php

this file is used:

> file.php?value1=red&value2=green

but the browser keeps showing red-green.php as you entered it.

In file.php you can get the $_GET values as usual:

```
$color1 = $_GET["value1"];
$color2 = $_GET["value2"];
```

Maybe this is what you were looking for.